# Docker build error with vue-cli Webpack boilerplate

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, webpack, eslint

I'm getting an error when trying to create a Docker build using vue-cli Webpack boilerplate. I can build locally just fine with the following versions of Node and npm

```
Node v7.10.0
npm v4.6
```

The command to do a production build *npm run build* is successful on my local machine.

The same command in docker produces the following error:

```
    ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: Error: No ESLint configuration found.
    at getLocalConfig (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:162:35)
    at Config.getConfig (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:260:26)
    at processText (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:224:33)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:754:26)
    at lint (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:211:17)
    at Object.module.exports (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:206:21)
```

Docker is working with Node v7.10.0 and npm v4.2. There is also an *eslintrc.js* file defined at the root of the project (this is part of the boilerplate), which is why the error in the Docker build isn't making any sense to me.

Here is a snippet from the Travis script that is run:

```
Here's a snippet from the Travis script:


Step 9/13 : RUN node --version
 ---> Running in 4730f2bef915
v7.10.0
 ---> b3c506ed854e
Removing intermediate container 4730f2bef915
Step 10/13 : RUN npm --version
 ---> Running in 790d18ac9d13
4.2.0
 ---> a43de03a2cc6
Removing intermediate container 790d18ac9d13
Step 11/13 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 210471cdc4f6
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@4.2.0
npm info using node@v7.10.0
npm info lifecycle STRAP@1.0.0~preinstall: STRAP@1.0.0
npm info linkStuff STRAP@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle STRAP@1.0.0~install: STRAP@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle STRAP@1.0.0~postinstall: STRAP@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle STRAP@1.0.0~prepublish: STRAP@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle STRAP@1.0.0~prepare: STRAP@1.0.0
npm info ok 
 ---> e0d7ba027db6
Removing intermediate container 210471cdc4f6
Step 12/13 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 8caee1365384
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@4.2.0
npm info using node@v7.10.0
npm info lifecycle STRAP@1.0.0~prebuild: STRAP@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle STRAP@1.0.0~build: STRAP@1.0.0
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: Error: No ESLint configuration found.
    at getLocalConfig (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:162:35)
    at Config.getConfig (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:260:26)
    at processText (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:224:33)
    at CLIEngine.executeOnText (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine.js:754:26)
    at lint (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:211:17)
    at Object.module.exports (/usr/local/strap/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:206:21)
  Build complete.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm that the name of the file is `.eslintrc.js` rather than `eslintrc.js`? It needs to be the former. http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats

Comment: Yes, it is .eslintrc.js

Comment: @user2360062 might be a volumes issue?

I can confirm that I have a very recent version of vue webpack boiler plate up and running inside of a docker container so it DOES work.  Most of the time the issues that people run into relate to Webpack Dev Server (ie. detecting changes etc for hot module reload).

What does your docker run command look like?

Comment: I've edited my original post to include a snippet from the Travis script that runs. Hope this helps to clarify the issue. Thanks again for helping out.